# When I do a React-native Debugger

Tags: react-native

When I do a React-native Debugger, I get an error like this. It was a project started in Windows PC. I am currently working on MacOs. I uploaded the photo of the error message. I will be glad if you help. There is no vacation for those who want to be a software developer.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXpOf.png)

> **Error message :**
> An error occurred while launching the application. Unknown error: not all success patterns were matched.
> It means that "react-native run-android" command failed.
> Please, check the View -> Toggle Output -> React Native,
> View -> Toggle Output -> React Native: Run android output windows. (error code 712) (error code 303)

launch.json code =>

```
{
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
          
          {
            "name": "Debug Android Hermes - Experimental",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnativedirect",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android"
          },
    
          {
            "name": "Debug Android",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android"
          }
            
        ]
    }
```